# Email validation of values stored in a dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to validate email addresses stored in a datafarme in `Azure Databricks`.

I tried using validate_email, but this is giving me an error as `No module named validate_email`

```
from validate_email import validate_email

df1 = emailvalidation[emailvalidation["EmailAddress"].apply(validate_email)]
print (df1)
```

I am expecting to see the valid email addresses from the data frame to be tagged as valid/invalid and stored to a different DF.

Comment: This simply means the module validate_email is not there

Comment: you need `pip install validate_email` to install that module

Comment: I have installed the module and here is my code:

Comment: from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError
def validate_e(x):
    try:
        v = validate_email(x)
        return True
    except EmailNotValidError as e:
        return False

df = emailvalidation["EmailAddress"].apply(validate_e)

Comment: Now it says column object is not callable.Note:emailvalidation is the dataframe where i have stored all the email addresses

Answer (score 1):

You can use user defined function `udf` to achieve this, for example

```
from validate_email import validate_email
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

valid_email_udf = udf(lambda e: validate_email(e), BooleanType())

emailvalidation.withColumn('is_valid', valid_email_udf('EmailAddress')).show()

+--------------------+--------+
|               email|is_valid|
+--------------------+--------+
|waqas.siddiqi@hot...|    true|
|                inva|   false|
+--------------------+--------+
```

Comment: from email_validator import validate_email
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

valid_email_udf = udf(lambda e: validate_email(e), BooleanType())

emailvalidation.EmailAddress('is_valid', valid_email_udf('email')).show()

Comment: what is the type of `emailvalidation.EmailAddress` ?

Comment: emailvalidation is my spark datafarme where EmailAddress is the column

Comment: so your code should be `emailvalidation.withColumn('is_valid', valid_email_udf('EmailAddress')).show()`

Comment: @shamakhan i have updated my answer with your example

Comment: Thank you.  think i code will work but the error is 'No module named 'validate_email'

Comment: i have email_validator instaled but i dont think it will work

Comment: @shamakhan i am not sure what do you mean "i dont think it will work" because i just tested on my pc, working perfectly fine! You can check the module if installed correctly or not by calling `print(validate_email('abc@xyz.com'))`

Comment: This is working. But now the error is different 'Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o5321.showString'

Comment: well this is completely different error, not sure what the df looks like, are u getting this when calling show()?

Comment: Yes, looks like it.

Comment: are u able to call `emailvalidation.show()` without any issue?

Comment: Yes this is working perfectly fine. The only issue is how do the validate email addresses stored in emailvalidation dataframe

Comment: so i just checked, the error `'Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o5321.showString` occurs when "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space". So, seems like your instance doesn't have enough memory.

Comment: what is the solution to this. If i take show() out it shows no error

Comment: increase the size of your cluster, https://forums.databricks.com/questions/650/how-can-i-increate-sparkexecutormemory.html
In spark nothing happens until you call an action, just like `show()`

Comment: import re
valid_re = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z0-9-_]+(.[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(.[A-Za-z]{2,})')
# or something like re.compile(r'\S+@\S+')
def validate_email(EmailAddress):
    if(valid_re.match(EmailAddress)):
        'valid'
    else:
        'invalid'
df=emailvalidation.withColumn('is_valid', valid_email_udf('EmailAddress'))
#df.show()

Comment: As soon as i do df.show() it is giving me the folllowing error:

Comment: SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 625.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 625.0 (TID 3892, 10.139.64.5, executor 0): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException

Comment: Does anyone have any idea

Comment: you need to post complete exception for us to help

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to validate emails in a column of a pyspark DataFrame:

Step 1. Define UDF

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import re
expr = r"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{| }~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?"
p = re.compile(expr)

email_validation_udf = udf(lambda email: True if p.match(email) else False )
```

Step 2: Validate emails in the pyspark DataFrame using the UDF

```
df_email = df_email.withColumn('EMAIL_VALIDATION_RESULT', email_validation_udf(F.lower(df_email.EMAIL_COLUMN_TO_VALIDATE)))
```